# How to update CPU's microcode with GRUB and chainload Windows 10?

Tags: boot, grub4dos

I would like to update microcode of my CPU before running Windows 10.

Idea is to use GRUB (here NeoGrub from https://neosmart.net/wiki/easybcd/neogrub/) for the task.

background:

why am I doing it? I have Intel motherboard with officially not supported Xeon x5470 CPU (so BIOS is not having its microcode available and Intel's BIOS is not patchable due to digital signatures); Windows 7 64b works fine but Windows 10 64b fails to boot (while the same machine with E8400 CPU boots successfully so the culprit lies in the CPU - probably missing compareexchange128 instruction which is probably provided through microcode update)

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install/windows-10-pro-upgrade-compareexchange128/f86d76d7-a2b7-4551-8a01-6d5169db2e22?auth=1

Update:

As per BIOS BITS mine X5470 has:

- Signature of 0001067a
- PlatformID of 00000004
- Microcode Revision of 00000a0b

and using latest microcodes from Intel there is nothing newer
and Windows 10 still hangs on booting :(

So I do confirm that the task can be achieved by BIOS BITS but it does not solve my problem unfortunately; it may be that BIOS is not turning some CPU features on (PAE, NX, SSE2); BIOS BITS should be able to do that as well I just need to learn how to do it...

hmm, it looks like that this CPU has no required features

```
ecx[13] cnpxchg16b=0
```

but from web searches I see that it is quite old instruction and it should be provided by this CPU; other users of this CPU report it as available (http://www.cpu-world.com/cgi-bin/CompareCPUID.pl?CPUID=47075&CPUID=47071&PROCESS=Compare+selected); could I just use wrmsr to turn it on?

Comment: ...this seems a really super complicated way to do a simple thing. Correct me if i'm wrong, but if you just want to load grub from the windows boot loader, why not just install say, Ubuntu on it's own partition without re-writing the MBR, then use easyBCD in windows to make the windows bootloader point to it? Then you can use Ubuntu's update-grub tool to detect any other OSes

Comment: Why do you need to update microcode manually? Isn't that the OS' duty? MS already ships out microcode update, if any, via Windows update

Comment: Blaine - I don't want to just chainload OS - I want to update microcode in the meantime; I had EasyBCD already installed so it was the simplest way to start with NeoGrub; @Lưu - it should be OS duty but my findings suggest that Windows 10 can't boot properly with x5470 Xeon's unless microcode is updated (so it may be doing the update but too late in the process); i will add more info as a background above

Comment: You can try updating your microcode from [within](http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/how-to-update-microcode-from-windows.787152/) windows.

Comment: very good comment @Marcho - you can post it as answer; unfortunately the result is the same as with BITS: microcode gets updated (from a07 to a0b) but cnpxchg16b is still absent :(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By using [VMware CPU Microcode Update Driver](https://labs.vmware.com/flings/vmware-cpu-microcode-update-driver)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible, but not using standard grub.

Please check whether the "BIOS BITS" project's bootloader would work. It *can* update the microcode and then chain-load the operating system, but it is a very, very advanced tool.

http://www.biosbits.org/

Answer (score 0):

Extracted from README.txt of BITS:

- "Configure Menu" contains options to temporarily reconfigure your system.
  None of these options will touch your BIOS or permanently change your system
  configuration, but they will override that configuration for the current boot
  only.

Therefore, you can indeed load a microcode, but apparently for that single boot session only!